# Why does Visual Studio generate garbled output windows?

Tags: c++, utf-8, visual-studio-2022

[image]

I don't know why it's garbled, and I didn't set any encoding format. My source code was set to utf-8 or that before.

I tried changing the code file encoding format, but it didn't work. My VS is a new install. It's not clear why this problem arises.

I want this output to be free of garbled:

```
  ע��: �����ļ�:  C:\Users\33442\CodeSpace\CLionProjects\Tina\engine\base\AbstractWindow.hpp
  [2/126] Scanning C:\Users\33442\CodeSpace\CLionProjects\Tina\src\main.cpp for CXX dependencies
  ע��: �����ļ�:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\iostream
  ע��: �����ļ�:   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\yvals_core.h
  ע��: �����ļ�:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vcruntime.h
  ע��: �����ļ�:     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\sal.h
  ע��: �����ļ�:      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\concurrencysal.h
  ע��: �����ļ�:     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\vadefs.h
  ע��: �����ļ�:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\xkeycheck.h
  ע��: �����ļ�:   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\istream
  ע��: �����ļ�:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\ostream
```

Comment: Your screenshot shows what looks to be a non-default font used in Visual Studio's Output window. Check Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Output Window

Comment: I use the JetBrainsMono NFM Medium font, which I used to use before, and it doesn't mess up. I had a broken SSD before, and I had no choice but to buy a new hard drive and reinstall the system and VS, and now it is garbled.

Comment: When I set the output window to default, it's still garbled, and it's the same for changing the font.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try resetting VS's option. Then repair in Visual Studio Installer. And set non-Unicode language setting in your PC's `language & region` setting.

Comment: I've given up, I uninstalled and installed VisualStudio three times, the first two times were the Community Edition, and I didn't uninstall the clean configuration file, this time I installed the Pro Edition, and the configuration was also cleaned up, and it was still the same garbled characters.